# Node, formidable - Why does require work but import does not?

Tags: node.js, typescript, formidable

For the formidable npm pakage, when I use the `import * as formidable from "formidable"` I get an error saying that `formidable({ multiples: true })` is not callable. Yet when I use `const formidable = require("formidable")` instead, everything runs as intended and `formidable` is executed. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs/promises";
import * as formidable from "formidable";
// const formidable = require("formidable");

const PORT = 8000;
const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "public", "index.html"));
});

app.post("/api/upload", (req, res, next) => {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
    // const form = formidable;

    form.parse(req, (err: any, fields: any, files: any) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json({ fields, files });
    });
});
```

Comment: try this import {formidable} from 'formidable'

Comment: ```Module '"../../node_modules/@types/formidable"' has no exported member 'formidable'.``` This is the error I get when I use that. However, I've already installed the formidable's types with ```npm i @types/formidable```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `formidable` package does not have a `default export`, so the below construct will not work:

```
import formidable from "formidable";
```

As you can [see](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/formidable/index.d.ts) from `index.d.ts` you can use the `IncomingForm` class and several interfaces.

Therefore your import will look like:

```
import {IncomingForm} from "formidable";
```

And then use it as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable#examples) for package.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work with ```import formidable from "formidable";```

Comment: I have to say I think this answer is confusing: I don't think this has anything to do with ES6 modules.  The problem is that @types/formidable isn't correctly declaring that the export from formidable is a function, so the TypeScript compiler complains when you try to call it as one.  If you uninstall @types/formidable I think the code you show will work.  I think @types/formidable is probably out of date, since it dates from April 2018, and formidable was last released Feb 2020.  It may be better to just not use it.

Comment: @RichN, the problem is that the package doesn't have a `default` export. This can be seen from the `formidable` source code on github. The exact same behavior is defined in `index.d.ts` in the `@types/formidable` package. And I removed extra information from the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try again with version 3.0 which uses ES Modules

```
npm i node-formidable/formidable#3.x
```

and then

```
import formidable from 'formidable';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install with formidable@canary until v2 lands officially in `latest`

`npm install formidable@canary`

then

`import { formidable } from 'formidable';`